# System.IO.IOException: 'The document has no pages

Tags: c#, itext

i am a complete newbie with no background on codding or any education on it
was trying some tutorial in youtube. it was creating a pdf file using windows visual c#.. i ran some problem while debugging it.. it just say the document has no pages.

```
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35);
        PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("New.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        doc.Open();
        doc.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph("Hello World"));
        doc.Close();
```

Comment: do you have a new.pdf file in the same directory as the compiled dll ?

Comment: debug, read document, or search and change to another library.

Comment: *"i ran some problem while debugging it.. it just say the document has no pages."* - which problem exactly? Who says that when?

Answer (score 0):

Check:

IOException:

> 1. Make sure your directory exists in your project PC.
> 2. Is your file Exists?.
> 3. Check filename if it is correct.